# Are there traits exhibiting avoidance of the mean?

Tags: genetics

Sometimes if two organisms with an unusually large value of a continuous trait mate their offspring on average will not have a value as large as one might naively expect. [Regression toward the mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_toward_the_mean) is the name for this phenomenon.

If I understand correctly for it to happen it is essential that the trait is controlled by recessive genes.

However if there was a continuous trait controlled by dominant genes or genes with [heterozygote advantage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterozygote_advantage) we would instead observe *avoidance* of the mean right? Is there a real-world example of this?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. What is a "recessive gene" (you almost certainly mean allele) and why do you think dominance/recessiveness is associated with regression to the mean? Please [edit] your post to address the above issues and include support (preferably including references to peer-reviewed sources) for the multiple assumptions you are making. You might also benefit from thinking about the genetics behind a "continuous" trait. Finally, please clarify why you think "dominant genes" would show "avoidance of the mean" — it may be that by working through the logic you will answer this yourself.

Comment: What is a “continuous trait”? What is a “mean right”? I’m afraid that if you come from a numerical discipline and ask questions on a biological site, they need to be expressed in a language we can understand.

Comment: By "recessive genes" I guess you mean genes such that the recessive phenotype has a larger value of the trait?

Comment: Then the reasoning from Wikipedia applies - The phenomenon is better understood if we assume that the inherited trait (e.g., height) is controlled by a large number of recessive genes. Exceptionally tall individuals must be homozygous for increased height mutations at a large proportion of these loci. But the loci which carry these mutations are not necessarily shared between two tall individuals, and if these individuals mate, their offspring will be on average homozygous for "tall" mutations on fewer loci than either of their parents.